# Is there a way to create a calculated column based on multiple conditions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

For a part of a research project my team and I are conducting, we need to find a way to create a calculated column that sum column *Change* when column *Trigger* does not equal NaN and stops summing when column *Release* = 1. Here is an example of what we're looking for...

Starting with the dataframe below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Change': [ -4.88, -10.14, -11.77, -10.09, 5.02, -3.20, -18.78, -18.47, 11.95, -15.49, -2.41], 'Trigger': [ NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -18.47, NaN, NaN, NaN], 'Release' : [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0]})
```

```
Change Trigger Release  
-4.88   NaN 0    
-10.14  NaN 0    
-11.77  NaN 0    
-10.09  NaN 1    
5.02    NaN 0    
-3.2    NaN 1    
-18.78  -18.47  0    
-18.47  NaN     0        
11.95   NaN     1        
-15.49  NaN     1        
-2.41   NaN     0
```

We've tried a myriad of ways, one being the below where the kernel just keeps spinning before eventually timing out.

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    if df['Trigger'][i] != np.nan:
        while df['Release'][i] == 0:
            df.loc[df.index[i], 'Sum'] = df['Change'][i]
```

Here is an example of the desired output.

```
Change Trigger Release  Sum
-4.88   NaN 0    NaN
-10.14  NaN 0    NaN
-11.77  NaN 0    NaN
-10.09  NaN 1    NaN
5.02    NaN 0    NaN
-3.2    NaN 1    NaN
-18.78  -18.47  0    NaN
-18.47  NaN     0        -18.47
11.95   NaN     1        11.95
-15.49  NaN     1        NaN
-2.41   NaN     0        NaN
```

The -18.47 in the *Trigger* column starts putting the values in the next *Change* column until the *Release* column demonstrates a 1.

Comment: what was the problem with your first attempts?

Comment: The loop just continuously runs